# Returning values and displaying values in a function on conditional basis

Tags: powershell

Good day!

I have a requirement where a function can be called implicitly or explicitly and accordingly the output should either be just print or just return value.

Below is my sample function :

```
FUNCTION TEST1
{

 

$x= "1","2","3"

 

for ($i=0;$i-lt $x.length;$i++)
{
write-host "This is " $x[$i]
}

 

return $x

 

}
```

How to ensure only Print statements are executed and the return value is not displayed when the function is called individually.

So based on above scenario, the ask is when the function is called individually, I just need to display the values as

This is 1

This is 2

This is 3

How to suppress the return value to be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired functionality, where the function can be invoked to either display output or provide a return value, you can introduce a parameter to manage this behavior. Here's a modified version of your function with this parameter

```
function Test1 {
    param (
        [switch]$PrintOnly
    )

    $x = "1", "2", "3"

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $x.Length; $i++) {
        Write-Host "This is $($x[$i])"
    }

    if (-not $PrintOnly) {
        return $x
    }
}
```

## Call the function to print only

```
Test1 -PrintOnly
```

## Call the function to return a value

```
$result = Test1
```

the Test1 function takes a `PrintOnly` parameter, which is a switch parameter. When you call the function with `PrintOnly`, it will only execute the printing part of the code and won't return anything. When you call the function without PrintOnly, it will return the array.

Example usage:

> `Test1 PrintOnly`: This will call the function and only display the
> values without returning anything. `$result = Test1`: This will call
> the function and assign the array to the $result variable. By using
> the PrintOnly parameter, you can control whether the function should
> print the values or return the array based on your requirements.